# Access Host-local ports from inside pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networking

I have an on-prem kubernetes cluster with an app that runs on host nodes (ie not in pods, on the host nodes themselves). The app is currently bound to a localhost port. I'm looking to access the app both from pods in the cluster and externally via ingress. But I'm trying to avoid opening the port on host firewalls.

I've tried running nginx pods as a daemon both with and without hostNetwork to proxy to the hosts' localhost. But without opening the firewall, none of my other pods can access that either. Anyone else run into this issue?

Basically, I'm trying to get the cluster to reach localhost ports on the host nodes.

```
[any random pod] -> [pod on node01] -> [node01 127.0.0.1:8000]  
[any random pod] -> [pod on node02] -> [node02 127.0.0.1:8000]  
[any random pod] -> [pod on node03] -> [node03 127.0.0.1:8000]
```

OR

```
[ingress running on node01]  -> [node01 127.0.0.1:8000]  
[ingress running on node01]  -> [node02 127.0.0.1:8000]  
[ingress running on node01]  -> [node03 127.0.0.1:8000]
```

Comment: Hello @Eric Gagnon Previously you mentioned about access to your app both from pods in the cluster and externally via ingress. After that you  just described problems with pod access. What is the main problem? Could you please provide more details about your issue, what is work as expected already and which problem is not resolved yet.

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin I added to my question - hopefully that clarifies my goal.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? Are you have still this problem?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor unfortunately, no updates - I had to bind to 0.0.0.0 on the host and open the specific ports in the firewall. Not ideal, but we have other protections in place and we're on an intranet.

Answer (score 0):

just for someone to look for an answer like me. I tried to follow-up OP's solution in comments, but I do not have an intranet network, so I cannot just point blank config 0.0.0.0 and open ports wide open in firewall. Localhost service is still listening on 0.0.0.0, but I opened firewall for K8s node subnet, so all the pods running on the server with their own IP from the subnet range are able to access localhost network.

I hope this helps someone.